# How to make one bar-chart from different data-frames with same format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have three different data-frames that have same format and I can not combine them because each one represent different data source.  I would like to show percentage of one variable for different data frames in one bar chart.

I can get bar-chart for column1 of one dataframe by using:

```
  ggplot(baseline, aes(x = c1)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),fill="blue",colour="blue") +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label=scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count")
```

I want output similar to this plot(except that I am showing percentage of each category) while race will be name of different data-frames and factor is values of column 1 of data frames.

[image]

Comment: Why not add a column for data source to each data.frame then combine the data.frames?

Comment: @dayne I can not do it because they have different size and that is the reason I am showing the percentage not count for frequency.

Comment: Size doesn't matter -- you could still calculate the percentage by source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use `ggplot2` but here is an illustration of how to accomplish what you want. It will be easiest to add a column to your data.frames indicating the source of each data.frame. Then calculate whatever metric you want, by source, then plot. Alternatively, you could calculate the metrics first, then combine the data.frames.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
make_data <- function() {
  n <- sample(5:10, 1)
  data.frame(id = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = n),
             vals = c(rnorm(n, 5, 1), rnorm(n, 10, 1), rnorm(n, 15, 1)))
}
df1 <- make_data()
df2 <- make_data()
df3 <- make_data()
df4 <- make_data()

df1$src <- "source1"
df2$src <- "source2"
df3$src <- "source3"
df4$src <- "source4"

dat <- do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3, df4))
dat <- as.data.table(dat)
res <- dat[ , mean(vals), by  = list(id, src)][order(id)]
barplot(height = res$V1, col = rep(brewer.pal(4, "Set1"), 3))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the `ggplot2` code provided by [Sumedh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5338586/sumedh):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(res, aes(x = id, y = V1, fill = src)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Sure. One more question! My C1 is factor variable and I want to show percentage of each value of that category across different sources not like your example. for instance, c1 values are male and female. I get error when I edit your code to get percentage of male or female for difference sources.any idea?

Comment: @Sajjad You should ask a new question with a clear reproducible example.